# PHP Codeigniter on XAMPP apache localhost - only the default controller is opening

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, xampp

At the moment whenever I try to access my page on localhost the base url works ie `localhost/example` but whenever I try to access any controllers I get a 404 error. I realise that this question is very similar to a couple other questions but I have tried these answers and they haven't worked.

My .htaccess looks like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I have also made the necessary changes to my routes and config file as below

**Config**

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

**Routes**

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this htaccess below seems to work fine with xampp and windows 7 and 8

Create a file .htaccess in main directory

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then make on config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

If your using codeigniter 3 make sure all controllers have there first letter capitalized Example.php

route.php

```
$route['example'] = "example"; 

$route['example'] = 'example';
```

Then the project url should be like

```
http://localhost/project-name/example
```